# Convert Base64 string to JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I have Base64 Encoded string and want to convert it to JSON object.

Here is encoded String

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQU...`

Here is how i am doing.

```
 String json = {"image": encode_string};
        try{
            JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(json);
            Log.d("My App", obj.toString());
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when i write this line `String json = {"image":encode_string};`i got compile time error.

> Unexpected Token

How to resolve that Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the JSONObject like a HashMap instead of having it parse a string.
This also removes the need for the try-catch.

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject();
obj.put("image", encode_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String json = {"image": encode_string};`

The right side of this equation doesn't return string value. Instead what you should do is:

`String json = "{" + "\"image\":"  + encode_string + "}";`